# Qt С++ | Поиск виджетов

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Суть: при нажатии одной кнопки на форме динамически создаются лейблы с уникальными именами
При нажатии второй кнопки, должен выделять определенный лейбл(имя которого задано)
Вопрос: как реализовать поиск? через FindChild?

Comment: ИМХО проще сохранять при создании лейблы в какой-нить вектор или мапу и не заниматься такими противоестественными вещами, как поиск объектов по именам...

Comment: Что вас смущает?

Comment: Да, через FindChild например.